# Code to display larget picture, using Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="container-images">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/small-1-big.jpg" alt="Main Image" id="myPicture">
  </figure>
  <div class="thumb_img_list">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/small-1.jpg" alt="Small image 1" id="small-1"></li>
      <li><img src="img/small-2.jpg" alt="Small image 2" id="small-2"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/small-3.jpg" alt="small image 3" id="small-3"></li>
      <li><img src="img/small-4.jpg" alt="small image 4" id="small-4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
function registerGalleryEvents() {

  let pic1 = document.getElementById('small-1');
  pic1.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic1); });
  
  let pic2 = document.getElementById('small-2');
  pic2.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic2); });
  
  let pic3 = document.getElementById('small-3');
  pic3.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic3); });
  
  let pic4 = document.getElementById('small-4');
  pic4.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic4); }); 

}
```

So far so good, I think. Maybe I should create a more scaleable solution and store the pictures in an iterable container and add events by traversing its contents. Like an array for example.

**Code to display larger picture (STUCK HERE):**

```
//declaring the displayImage function
function displayImage(thumbnail){
 
  document.getElementById('myPicture').src ="img/"; //unfinished code
}
```

I'm totaly stuck here and would appreciate any advice you have for me on how to solve this.

Comment: Do you have a programming question?

Comment: Is your issue with the implementation of `displayImage()` or is your issue with going about creating a more scalable solution?

Comment: displayImage().

Comment: Is the big version of the image always suffixed with `-big`?

Comment: Yes. I tried to go with document.getElementById('myPicture').src ="img/+endsWith(-big.jpg"); but it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on an image, you can grab its `src` attribute using [`.getAttribute("src")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute#Non-existing_attributes). This will allow you to then extract the name from it and the image's extension. For example, if you click on `small-2.jpg`, then [splitting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) this src on a `"."` will give an array with the first index containing `"small-2"` and the second index containing the extension `"jpg"`. You can then extract these into variables, I've done this using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Then you can update the main image's `src` to contain the image name you extracted suffixed with `"-big"` along with the extension type.

See example below (inspect the page's source to see image `src` changes since these are all alts):

```js
function registerGalleryEvents() {
  let pic1 = document.getElementById('small-1');
  pic1.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic1); });
  
  let pic2 = document.getElementById('small-2');
  pic2.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic2); });
  
  let pic3 = document.getElementById('small-3');
  pic3.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic3); });
  
  let pic4 = document.getElementById('small-4');
  pic4.addEventListener('click', e => { displayImage(pic4); }); 

}

function displayImage(thumbnail){
  const currentImgSrc = thumbnail.getAttribute("src");
  const [imgName, ext] = currentImgSrc.split(".");

  document.getElementById('myPicture').src = imgName + '-big.' + ext;
}

registerGalleryEvents();
```

```html
<div class="container-images">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/small-1-big.jpg" alt="Main Image" id="myPicture">
  </figure>
  <div class="thumb_img_list">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/small-1.jpg" alt="Small image 1" id="small-1"></li>
      <li><img src="img/small-2.jpg" alt="Small image 2" id="small-2"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/small-3.jpg" alt="small image 3" id="small-3"></li>
      <li><img src="img/small-4.jpg" alt="small image 4" id="small-4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

As for a more scalabale solution, youu can give each clickable small image a class name so that you can put them into a container/[NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) like you mentioned (the NodeList is returned by the [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method). Once you have done this, you can loop through the elements in the NodeList and add the event listener:

```js
function registerGalleryEvents() {
  const galleryImgs = document.querySelectorAll(".galleryImg");
  galleryImgs.forEach((galleryImg) => {
    galleryImg.addEventListener("click", () => {
      displayImage(galleryImg);
    });
  });
}

function displayImage(thumbnail){
  const currentImgSrc = thumbnail.getAttribute("src");
  const [imgName, ext] = currentImgSrc.split(".");
  document.getElementById('myPicture').src = imgName + '-big.' + ext;
}

registerGalleryEvents();
```

```html
<div class="container-images">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/small-1-big.jpg" alt="Main Image" id="myPicture">
  </figure>
  <div class="thumb_img_list">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/small-1.jpg" class="galleryImg" alt="Small image 1" id="small-1"></li>
      <li><img src="img/small-2.jpg" class="galleryImg" alt="Small image 2" id="small-2"></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="img/small-3.jpg" class="galleryImg" alt="small image 3" id="small-3"></li>
      <li><img src="img/small-4.jpg" class="galleryImg" alt="small image 4" id="small-4"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast reply. 
I tried to come up with a more scaleable solution when it comes to registerGalleryEvents().
Here is my example:

`let imgNames = ['small-1', 'small-2', 'small-3', 'small-4']
for (img in imgNames) {
  document.getElementById(img).addEventListener('click', e => {
    displayImage(img);
  });
}`

But it didn't work. Am I missing something here? Or do you perhaps know a better solution?

Comment: @Lexlecter Have you seen the second half of my answer (there is a collapsed code snippet which you can expect). Your solution should work if you change `for (img in imgNames)` to `for (let img of imgNames)`